# Unable to disable form submit with an input button that is an image

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

How do I disable the form from submitting? I have tried the following chunk of jQuery with no success - any ideas?

http://pastebin.com/W7hjaSe0

```
$('#signup').submit(function(){
    $('input[type=button]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your selector, this is not a "button" type

Change

```
$('input[type=button]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

To

```
$('input#signup', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are looking for the button to be physically greyed out, or just prevent default action. Here is an example that will run your code on click, grey out the button, and then prevent the default form submission behavior.

```
$('#signup').submit(function(){
     $('input[type=button]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').css('opacity',0.5); 
     return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `return false` should do the trick. If that doesn't work you can always use the `preventDefault()` function of event.